# NivoSlider not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing a problem with my new website. I have set up a slider at the frontend but it does not load any image i put in. What is blocking the slider? I have been installing a theme over a old theme as i cannot import configurable products etc and this is way faster.

What can block it and how can i find out?

[image: Image not loading]

This is the errors i get in the Console:

[image: Errors console]

Any idea?